# HDMI audio not working (?) on SoC Celeron N3350, analog audio works [sof-essx8336]

Tags: debian, audio, alsa, hdmi, alsamixer

I have just installed Debian 12 on a mini PC equipped with Celeron N3350. The goal is to use it for bluray playback. So far the video is smooth, but I can get audio only from the jack analog output.

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofessx8336 [sof-essx8336], device 0: ES8336 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofessx8336 [sof-essx8336], device 5: HDMI 1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofessx8336 [sof-essx8336], device 6: HDMI 2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofessx8336 [sof-essx8336], device 7: HDMI 3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

So I tried

```
>aplay -D plughw:0,0 ~/Wav_868kb.wav
Playing WAVE '/home/roberto/Wav_868kb.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo
```

and it gives sound on the analog jack output.

Using the same commands for 5,6,7  `aplay -D plughw:0,5 ~/Wav_868kb.wav` I hear nothing from my projector (audio-capable) connected via HDMI (it plays sound on this device using Windows 10).

I checked `alsa-mixer` and I cannot identify anything clearly "HDMI", despite `/proc/asound/devices` has theright devices

```
  1:        : sequencer
  2: [ 0- 0]: digital audio playback
  3: [ 0- 0]: digital audio capture
  4: [ 0- 5]: digital audio playback
  5: [ 0- 6]: digital audio playback
  6: [ 0- 7]: digital audio playback
  7: [ 0- 2]: hardware dependent
  8: [ 0]   : control
 33:        : timer
```

What do I do wrong here? what need to be fixed/verified to get HDMI sound out?

At the kernel level I do not see major issues, as seen below, but maybe I am wrong.

```
sudo journalctl -b | grep -i 8336
Jun 17 13:12:20 4K-BOX kernel: sof-essx8336 sof-essx8336: quirk mask 0x5
Jun 17 13:12:20 4K-BOX kernel: sof-essx8336 sof-essx8336: quirk SSP5
Jun 17 13:12:20 4K-BOX kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-apl 0000:00:0e.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware intel/sof-tplg/sof-apl-es8336-ssp5.tplg
Jun 17 13:12:20 4K-BOX kernel: sof-essx8336 sof-essx8336: ASoC: Parent card not yet available, widget card binding deferred
Jun 17 13:12:20 4K-BOX kernel: es8316 i2c-ESSX8336:00: assuming static mclk
Jun 17 13:12:20 4K-BOX kernel: input: sof-essx8336 Headset as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/sof-essx8336/sound/card0/input15
Jun 17 13:12:20 4K-BOX kernel: input: sof-essx8336 HDMI/DP,pcm=5 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/sof-essx8336/sound/card0/input16
Jun 17 13:12:20 4K-BOX kernel: input: sof-essx8336 HDMI/DP,pcm=6 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/sof-essx8336/sound/card0/input17
Jun 17 13:12:20 4K-BOX kernel: input: sof-essx8336 HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/sof-essx8336/sound/card0/input18
```

```
[Sat Jun 17 13:12:20 2023] sof-essx8336 sof-essx8336: quirk mask 0x5
[Sat Jun 17 13:12:20 2023] sof-essx8336 sof-essx8336: quirk SSP5
[Sat Jun 17 13:12:20 2023] sof-audio-pci-intel-apl 0000:00:0e.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware intel/sof-tplg/sof-apl-es8336-ssp5.tplg
[Sat Jun 17 13:12:20 2023] sof-essx8336 sof-essx8336: ASoC: Parent card not yet available, widget card binding deferred
[Sat Jun 17 13:12:20 2023] es8316 i2c-ESSX8336:00: assuming static mclk
[Sat Jun 17 13:12:20 2023] input: sof-essx8336 Headset as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/sof-essx8336/sound/card0/input15
[Sat Jun 17 13:12:20 2023] input: sof-essx8336 HDMI/DP,pcm=5 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/sof-essx8336/sound/card0/input16
[Sat Jun 17 13:12:20 2023] input: sof-essx8336 HDMI/DP,pcm=6 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/sof-essx8336/sound/card0/input17
[Sat Jun 17 13:12:20 2023] input: sof-essx8336 HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/sof-essx8336/sound/card0/input18
```

Comment: Apparently `aplay -D plughw:0,5 ~/Wav_868kb.wav` works if I unmute a level called S/PDIF (which is not the same as HDMI, afaik).

Comment: Is this reproducible with kernel 6.4-rc6? If it is, file a bug report here https://bugzilla.kernel.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Drivers under `Sound (ALSA)`